# Serialize an object as clear text

Tags: c#

> **Follow Up Question:** I noticed with the
>   binaryformatter that all I had to do
>   was mark the oject as serializable.
>   Looks like with the DataContracts I
>   have to mark each and every property I want serialized.
>   Is that correct?

How do I serialize my object to a file to where I can read and make changes to my **serialized** object (it's not binary but ...?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can serialize to XML, using the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) (or the older [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)).

You can also serialize to JSON using the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), if you find XML too verbose. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx).

Both formats are textual, but they are **not** clear text. I don't believe you can get a textual representation that will be clear text (as you require delimiters between different members, properties and values).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the XMLSerialization attribute.